# Python 2.7 packages and importing between directories

Tags: python-2.7, python-import, python-multithreading

Ok so I've been struggling with this for over a week now and I've tried various methods mentioned on this site and others on google but here goes. I'm running python 2.7. I've got a python script in the parent directory which calls a second script located in a child directory. The second script starts a different thread and does an os.system call to a third and final script. This third script needs to import something located in the parent directory. Can someone tell me what's wrong with this setup? I do have `__init__.py` located in every folder being used. And I do try adding the relative parent directory to the path. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
File Structure

Parent Directory
    Python_Script_1.py
    Imports_needed.py
    __init__.py
    Child Directory
        Python_Script_2.py
        Python_Script_3.py
        __init__.py
```

Method 1

```
Python_Script_2.py
import os
import sys
import multiprocessing

def listen():
    listen_string = "python ~/path/Python_Script_3.py"
    os.system(listen_string)

q = multiprocessing.Process(target=listen())




Python_Script_3.py
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
import Imports_needed
```

ImportError: No module named "Imports_needed"

Method 2

```
Python_Script_2.py
import os
import sys
import multiprocessing

def listen():
    listen_string = "python ~/path/Python_Script_3.py"
    os.system(listen_string)

q = multiprocessing.Process(target=listen())


Python_Script_3.py
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
from .. import Imports_needed
```

ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Question about method 2, how come it's telling me this is not a package despite each directory containing `__init__.py`?

Additionally, I've used something very similar to method 1 in the past but I cannot see any differences between my code or file structures. If anyone has any suggestions I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

EDIT: Apologies, I forgot something fairly significant in the description. There's a third file involved that I completely forgot about... So sorry :( Python_Script_2 makes a new thread via multiprocessing and does an os.system call to Python_Script_3. Python_Script_3 is located in the same child directory as Python_Script_2. Python_Script_3 is having the import issues when trying to import Imports_needed.py from the Parent Directory. I've updated the question to reflect this. (I'm sorry, I know this is a major detail that I left out but it's a complicated package and doing many more things than just what I'm asking about)

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
from Parent_Directory import Imports_needed
```

or

```
from Parent_Directory.Imports_needed import <your class or method>
```

Comment: First one resulted in "ImportError: No module named Parent_Directory"
(And I've made sure everything is spelled right, so it's not that)

Second one resulted in "ImportError: No module named Parent_Directory.Imports_needed"

Comment: make sure you do not have spaces in the dir names -> should be `Parent_Directory` and `Child_Directory`...

Comment: Yeah, there aren't any spaces

Comment: Apologies, I forgot something fairly significant in the description. There's a third file involved that I completely forgot about... So sorry :( Edits have been made to the original question

Answer (score 0):

You don't need

```
sys.path.append("..")
```

at all. If `Python_Script_2.py` is imported from the main script, import path inside of `Python_Script_2.py` will be relative to the main script. So

```
import Imports_needed
```

is enough.
Make sure you hava double underscore prefix for the file `_init__.py` in your child directory (in your example you have only 1 underscore symbol `_`).

UPDATE

If you rely on sys.path.append(), you should use:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.realpath('..'))
```

otherwise, `'..'` says nothing to the interpreter about your app environment.

Comment: The underscore was a typo on my example only. Using `import Imports_needed` resulted in "ImportError: No module named Imports_needed"

Comment: Apologies, I forgot something fairly significant in the description. There's a third file involved that I completely forgot about... So sorry :( Edits have been made to the original question

Comment: Perhaps you are facing the following scenario. You are calling `os.system("python ~/path/Python_Script_3.py")` command, which executes Python_Script_3.py directly and the latter becomes the 'main' program file of the subprocess. Naturaly it knows nothing about your import paths and about the parent directory, so it raises an exception which is printed to the output, which goes to the output of the parent process and you think that that was the parent process who produced the exception, while it is not.

Comment: Well the parent process runs to completion. It's just the child process that dies on the import

Comment: This is exactly what I am talking about. Sure the parent process runs to completion as there is no exception in it. Of course, the child process dies, as it does not know anything about your parent directory and raises an exception. Comment the `os.system(listen_string)` line, and you will see that there is no error any longer.
If you want to import the 3d file, you should start the subprocess from your main file and pass it a param to execute the 3d file:
`os.system("python ~/path/Python_Script_1.py --import-my-3d-file-param")`

Comment: but shouldn't my `sys.path.append("..")` within the child process take care of that?

Comment: Not quite. In this case you need `import os` and `import sys`, then
`sys.path.append(os.path.realpath('..'))`